# How can I troubleshoot a failed local network VNC connection?

Tags: networking, vnc, remmina

On Machine A, I start Remmina (0.9.3) and create a VNC Incoming Connection profile. I picked port 5900, with a username and password. No changes under advanced or SSH. I start the profile and it says "Listening on port 5900 for an incoming VNCI connection..."

On Machine B, I start Remmina and create a VNC profile. I set machinea.local:5900 as the server, enter the username and password and leave everything else as-is. I start the profile and it says "Connecting to 'username@machinea'..."

Patience is a virtue, but half an hour later there's still nothing but those message windows.

So far I've:

- Made sure UFW isn't enabled
- Confirmed I can ping and ssh from Machine A to Machine B and vice versa
- Tried on other ports
- Tried without a username and password
- Googled aimlessly
- Made a cup of tea

What's next?

Further actions taken:

- Confirmed I can successfully `telnet machinea.local 5900` from Machine B (thanks Pavlos G.)
- Run `ifconfig` on Machine A to get network IP address (10.0.0.x)
- Attempt ping, telnet and Remmina using IP address instead of hostname
- Confirm you're not trying to set up a reverse VNC connection
- Confirm you're using not trying to using client software as a server (doh!)

Comment: Can you telnet to port 5900? Is it open?

Comment: @pavlosg yes, if I `telnet machinea.local 5900` from Machine B I get a "Connected to machinea.local." message - I take it this is a more reliable test than pinging and ssh since it happens on the port in question? the problem remains but I've updated my list of actions! :)

Comment: Testing the specific application port is indeed more reliable. Have you tried to connect by an IP address or a hostname?

Comment: @pavlosg tried both, add IP address steps to my list troubleshooters? behaviour is the same using either hostname or IP address (after successfully telnetting in from Machine B, if I enter the escape character I get an empty warning box on Machine A and the incoming session is terminated)

Comment: @pavlosg more symptoms: if the listening server is running, the Machine B attempts to connect but never succeeds, if the listening server isn't running Machine B immediately says "Unable to connect"

Comment: Please check my answer, i hope it makes sense to you now ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the protocol option `VNC - Incoming Connection` is not what you expect.

Remmina's [wiki page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/remmina/index.php?title=Main_Page#VNC) talks about `reverse VNC connection` support.

This means that it reverses the usual procedure of a client connecting to a server.
It's mainly used when firewall/NAT issues are involved.

So, remmina on machine A is waiting for a VNC server on machine B to connect to it.
Therefore, remmina is still the client-side of the connection, not the server-side.

I've made the following test in order to give you an example of how the whole thing works:

- Created a new `VNC - Incoming Connection` to my linux box and started it.
  Now remmina is waiting for an incoming request from a **VNC Server - not a VNC client**
- Started tightVNC server on my windows box and selected `attach listening viewer` and added the ip address and port of my linux box
- Now my windows box is accessed remotely from remmina client.

Comment: thanks! I hadn't realised Remmina didn't have a VNC server option